# Find sufficient and necessary conditions on $a$ and $b$ such that the equation have solutions of the form $(x,y)=(0,y)$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let us consider the following equation 
$$ax+by=0$$
where $x$ and $y$ are the unknown variables and $a$ and $b$ are constants.

My **question** is: Find sufficient and necessary conditions on $a$ and $b$ such that the set of solutions of the system is precisely $\{\,(x,y)\mid x=0\,\}$.

Comment: Not clear what you are asking. $(x,y)=(0,0)$ would seem of the form $(0,y)$ and is _always_ a solution.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen: Yes, I add the condition $y≠0$

Comment: The question does not say that _all_ solutions must be of the form $(x,y)=(0,y)$. If you meant to say that (as I gather from the answer you accepted), you should have said that in the question.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen: Yes, I add that remark.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen: The condition $a≠0$ is not added in your answer.

Comment: The problem is that after changing the question again, it still is not what you want: by my initial comment you always get $(0,0)$ as solution, so requiring $y\neq0$ for all solutions is too strong to be possible. I guess I'll just edit your question so that it properly says what I think you meant all along.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $y=t$ then $x=-\frac{b}{a}t$ and hence the solution set is of the form $(x,y)=(-\frac{b}{a}t,t)$ so the condition is $b=0,a\ne 0$

Comment: @ Semsem: The condition $a≠0$ is not relevant.

Answer (score 1):

Since $(x,y)=(0,1)$ must be in the solution set, one gets 
If $a\times 0+b\times 1=0$ leading to $b=0$, and since $(x,y)=(1,0)$ must not be in the solution set one gets $a\times 1+b\times 0\neq0$ leading to $a\neq 0$;
these are therfore necessary conditions. Conversely, if $a\neq0$ and $b=0$ then you equation is $ax=0$ and after the allowed division by $a$ this gives $x=0$ as equivalent form, and the solution set is $\{\,(x,y)\mid x=0\,\}$ as required.
The necessary condition found above is therfore also sufficient; your answer is "$a\neq0$ and $b=0$".